# Facing problem while trying to insert data in database, LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I am getting this error "Class 'App\Models\Student' not found".

Please check my codes:

```
      <?php

          namespace App\Http\Controllers;

          use Illuminate\Http\Request;
           use App\Models\Student;
           class StudentController extends Controller
           {
              public function data(){


                   $stud = new Student;
                   $stud->name = 'Mona Lisa';
                   $stud->rollnumber = '001';
                   $stud->save();


             }
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code for your `Student` class?

Comment: Yeah...


          <?php

                     namespace App\Models;

                      use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

                 class Student extends Model
              {
                 protected $connection = 'mysql';
                  protected $primaryKey = 'id';
                  protected $table = 'students';
                    protected $fillable = array(
                       'id',
                       'name',
                      'rollnumber',
        
                      );

            public $timestamps = false;
         }

Comment: Where is the Student class file located?

Comment: Student class is Student.php model

Comment: @JnanBikashDeka Did you put your model class in a new directory? By default they don't have their own directory. They lie in the app directory with many other directories.

Comment: @JnanBikashDeka mind setting the answer as solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is most likely in the namespace declaration of the `Student` model.

check in your class file `App\Models\Student.php` that the namespace is correct.

```
namespace App\Models;
```

then try to run in the console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
use App\Models\Student;
```

to:

```
use App\Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggests that class is not loaded into the controller. I am guessing from the issue that you have created a separate directory for models if you have then you need to update your composer file to include new class paths for model classes. locate **autoload** in you composer.json file and add an entery in **classmap** array as shown below

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/models"
    ]
}
```

then on command line navigate to your project directory and run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and if you didn't create new models directory then just run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your namespace of student model

use `App\Models\Student` If your model is in App\Models directory 
`use App\Student` if your model is in app directory

Finally run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

check your namespace of student model

`use App\Models\Student` If your model is in `use App\Models` directory 
`use App\Student` if your model is in app directory

then go to command line and  run `composer dump-autoload`